# inserting hidden data in form with blade

Tags: forms, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I am trying to understand how I should treat data in a blade template for a form.
Let's say I have a view to which I send data from an ages_table from the db.
For example I will get these data from 2 columns in the ages_table id, age (1, 40 - 2 ,41 and so on).
Then my form displays a selector where you can chose your age, example 40.
Now.. when I perform the post I need to send the id of that age, in this case 1 and not the number (40) so that I can store it in a user_details table that references the Ages_table example in column age_id of user_details table, in this case 1.
What I am thinking is I need the id in the selector but it needs to be hidden so that when I post the data I only get the id and not the 40.. but maybe that's not how you do it in laravel and eloquent. Any hint?

Comment: This seems a case for..... Select input! Where you can place options with descriptions that have id's!  There's more! Select inputs can be placed inside forms, they have most of the HTML5 attributes like `required `. And you say, it's that it? NO!!! You can also define a selected option by default! For more info just visit this awesome webite -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: Yes I know it's a select input case anyway that is not the problem. The problem is the view receives the data from the DB but then displays only the Age. When the user selects the age the corresponding id must be sent back to be stored in the db. So the question is: how do you send back the id? Is it really necessary? Meaning maybe eloquent can do some magic of it's own?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you set the option value as the id?

```
<select name="age">
    @foreach($ages as $age)
        <option value="{{ $age->id }}">{{ $age->name }}</option>
    @endforeach 
</select>
```

So user selects age and server receives the ID of the selection.  Is your view not receiving this data?

Comment: Yes I thought about that too. Thanks